# Тестирование функции, принимающей параметры для ajax запроса. Sinon

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты, sinonjs

Впервые пишу такой тест

Не могу понять, как сделать правильного шпиона (spy), который будет вызван при удачном ajax-запросе.

Макет функции, которую надо протестировать:

```
testMe: function(param1, param2, fnSuccess, fnError) {
    ...Различная работа с переданными параметрами...
    $.ajax({
        url: '/myUrl/',
        data: { "param1": param1, "param2": param2 },
        success: fnSuccess
        error: fnError
    });
}
```

Необходимо в качестве колбэка на успех (success) передать шпиона, чтобы, когда он выполнится, я получил в тесте "ok". Пробовать разными способами, найболее близким, мне кажется, этот (его и публикую):

```
var server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
var callback = sinon.spy();
lock.setLock(param1, param2, callback, function() {});
server.respond();
ok(callback.called); <--failed
```

Однако, на выходе получаю **failed**

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

перехват всех XHR запросов на странице:

```
var tempGlobal;

function addXMLRequestCallback(callback) {
    var oldSend, i;
    if (XMLHttpRequest.callbacks) {
        XMLHttpRequest.callbacks.push(callback);
    } else {
        XMLHttpRequest.callbacks = [callback];
        oldSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
            for (i = 0; i < XMLHttpRequest.callbacks.length; i++) {
                XMLHttpRequest.callbacks[i](this);
            }
            oldSend.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
}

addXMLRequestCallback(function(xhr) {
    console.log(xhr);
});
```

Comment: a callback, я так полагаю, это sinon.spy? Кстати, у меня тест заработал, когда я стал использовать стаб (sinon.stub())

Comment: а, понятно, нет, у меня - общее решение, для sinon действительно надо использовать внутренние средства, stub

Comment: мне понравилось это решение, чтобы не потерять, я даже его куда-нибудь да впихну =)